# Accessing custom coordinates from a layer with d3.layout.stack()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, accessor

I have an array of data in the following form:

```
_data = [
    {key: <String>, values: [<number>...]}
]
```

If the 'values' variable in each JSON object were an array of JSON coordinates (i.e. "x: ?, y: ?"), I could just use the following:

```
d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) {
        return d.values;
    });
```

Instead, I need to read x from each layer's values array as the index in the values array, and y as the number. Like so:

```
_data = [
    {key: "oranges", values: [5, 6, 8]},
    {key: "bananas", values: [2, 1, 9]}
]

becomes

"oranges": (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 8);
"bananas": (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 9);
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the appropriate accessor function to access your specific data format from within D3's stack layout. The following code should do what you are looking for:

```
d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) {
        return d.values.map(function(y, i) {
            return { "x": i, "y": y };
        });
    });
```

The call to `.map()` will transform your `data.values` array and return an array consisting of objects having `x` and `y` coordinates set to the values you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
var data = [
    {key: "oranges", values: [5, 6, 8]},
    {key: "bananas", values: [2, 1, 9]}
];

var newData = [];
var fruit;
var coords;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  coords = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < data[i].values.length; x++) {
    coords.push([x, data[i].values[x]]);
  }

  fruit = {};
  fruit[data[i].key] = coords;
  newData.push(fruit);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Or something like this? Where you format only the array you need, when you need it?

```
d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) {
      var coords = [];
      for (var x = 0; x < d.values.length; x++) {
        coords.push([x, d.values[x]]);
      }
      return coords;
    });
```

Comment: I've considered just moving the values into an appropriately formatted array, but it would be much less efficient than just reading straight from the data I'm taking in, if that's even possible.

Comment: Not quite there. altocumulus got it. Thanks though.